# What marketplace / garage-sale software package does togoparts.com use?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, forum, software

See: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/opensource-marketplace-platform

I want to start a site also for end-users to buy/sell used sporting goods of a particular type.  When the scope of goods is narrowed like this, it is very advantageous to be able to filter by Brand, Size, Price Range, etc.

**Nice features:**

- account reputation with user comments
- listings sortable by many custom fields
- auto resize and recompress image uploads

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so does anyone know where I can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Magento Ecommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) seems to be the platform of the moment, with hosted prices from $15 - $125 per month and a [free community edition](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download).

There are also number of Wordpress [plugins](https://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&q=wordpress%20ecommerce%20plugins&oq=wordpress%20e&aq=2&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=hp.11.2.0l4.0l0l1l651l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=7a63589177af259b&biw=1920&bih=955&pf=p&pdl=300) that fulfill the same functionality (and WP is fully open source).

In general you could do this with any platform so long as you tag the items correctly when they're added to the system and setup the correct filter hierarchy so users can search with a search to refine the number of items found.